# Unable to connect to Docker PostgresSQL using IP Address

Tags: c#, postgresql, docker, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am using  C# Visual Studio 2022/.NET6. I am getting an exception when I try to connect PostgreSQL on the Docker container using the container IP Address `172.17.0.2`:

```
"Host=172.17.0.2:5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=xxxxx"
```

But when I connect using `localhost', the connection is successful:

```
"Host=localhost:5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=xxxxx"
```

***How I am installing PostgreSQL as Docker container***

```
Step 1 - Install Postgres

docker pull postgres
docker run --name gb-postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxx -d postgres

Step 2 - Once Postgres is installed you need to find out your instance IP address

Run
docker ps

copy the {id  of the container} of the container and run

docker inspect {id  of the container}

copy the IPAddress of the container

Step 3 - Configure API

Use IP address in your Program.cs
```

***Exception***

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 172.17.0.3:5432
 ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|203_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\data\code\Dust-IO\388013gb3\cloud\API\GB3API\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 14
```

***C# Program***

```
using System;
using Npgsql;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "Host=172.17.0.2;Database=GB3;Username=postgres;Password=xxxxx";

        using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected to PostgreSQL database.");

                // Perform database operations here

                connection.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection closed.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Even when I try to connect using Visual Studio 2022 extension `Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration`, I get an error `Exception while connecting`. And when I try to connect using VS Code extension `PostgreSQL by Chris Kolkman`, I get an error to connect `ETIMEDOUT 172.17.0.2:5432`.

***docker inspect***

```
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "d9371cf11864c75a9c35d03ce24bf90bb78af8f44b43e6336b0630a6d79d9503",
                    "EndpointID": "b235ae6eb713404f9fbbcd35453acb6e9dcb213ad6d51fa8809272912a569e15",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
```

Comment: you will have to use `localhost` instead of `172.17.0.x` when running outside of docker

Comment: @DanielA.White, is there a way to connect using IP Address? Because in production, I have to connect using IP Address.

Comment: Use configuration from the outside.

Comment: @DanielA.White, could you give example command line?

Comment: There’s many ways to do it. I suggest you look at Microsoft’s documentation

Comment: The ipv4 address for 'localhost' is spelled '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: @jjanes, 127.0.0.1 worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the `docker inspect` IP address is basically useless.  You can only use it at all in one very specific Docker configuration (running the Docker engine locally on a native-Linux host, without Docker Desktop).  There's never a reason to look it up and you don't need it in this case.

A more robust approach is to use a `docker run -p` option to publish a port from your container to the host, and then access that port.  This is what you're seeing in your setup: you're connecting to `Host=localhost` and to the first `docker run -p` port number.  This works on native Linux, with Docker Desktop, and possibly with one or two other setups as well.

A corollary to this is that the connection string will be different if your program is running in a container or not, and you can't really put it in source code like that.  From the host outside a container you'll need `localhost` and the published port number; from another container on the same Docker network you'll need the other container's name as a host name and the standard PostgreSQL port 5432 (`-p` port mappings are ignored here).  Environment variables can be a convenient way to provide these environment-specific settings.

If for whatever reason you need an IP address rather than a host name (which you suggest in comments), `localhost` is defined to be `127.0.0.1`.  Most client libraries for pretty much anything will accept either a DNS name or an IP address.

(At a technical level, the `docker inspect` IP address is only defined within a single Linux host.  On a native Linux system running the Docker engine directly `ifconfig` will show you the Docker-internal network interfaces and you can connect to them.  If you're on another host, though, these IP addresses aren't reachable at all.  Docker Desktop always runs a Linux VM, even on native Linux, and again the Docker-internal addresses aren't accessible from outside that VM.)